# How to check the reply to a message guilded.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, bots

I'm making a command that requires checking what the user is going to reply with to a bot's message. Here's some sample code:

```
async def create_channel(message):
    await message.reply("Reply to this with the channel name that you want to create")
```

How can I get the user's reply to this message? Have done the research, but didn't find it.

Comment: I haven't tried it and I'm not familiar with the guilded lib but I think you might be able to do it using the ChatMessage class, see here: https://github.com/shayypy/guilded.py/blob/9148fc67b27e5bd0822c4a0af5940abe9b905667/guilded/message.py#L530